# Volume of vessel

Tags: algebra-precalculus

[image]

I thought that in the 2nd process the volume of water removed is directly proportional to the probability of water present in the vessel. And similarly for wine. And using the same, we should be able to say the amount of water and wine that must have been removed as "mixture" from the vessel. Interestingly, this gives the volume of the vessel, which means there's something wrong here. So, where am I going wrong? And how should it be attempted?

[image]

Comment: Let $x$ denote the amount of wine in the vessel originally, which is the same thing as the volume of the vessel since the problem says the vessel is "full" of wine. After the first step the vessel contains $x-9$ liters of wine and 9 liters of water. The second step removes $9(\frac{x-9}{x})$ liters of wine and $9(\frac{9}{x})$ liters of water and then adds another 9 linters of water. Hence at the end the vessel has $x-9-9(\frac{x-9}{x})$ liters of wine and $9-9\frac{9}{x}+9$ liters of water. Solving the proportion gives $x=5$ or $x=45$. Obviously we throw out $x=5$.

Comment: As for where you went wrong: the term $(v_0-9)\left(\frac{v_0-9}{v_0}\right)$ is not correct. $\frac{v_0-9}{v_0}$ gives the fraction of the first mixture that is wine, and since you're removing 9 liters, you multiply this by 9 to get the number of liters of wine removed. The equation you're trying to write is the trivial identity $9(\frac{9}{v_0})+9(\frac{v_0-9}{v_0})=9$. But of course this is true for all values of $v_0$; you can't find the volume this way.